# MPI - work/pool example

Tags: c, mpi

is there any example of using work/pool (or. Producer/Consumer) scheme for MPI? As for everything I have done, I am getting just one going through application and my app is deadlocked then.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just googling around for "MPI Master Worker" or "MPI Master Slave", I see a bunch of examples; one good one hosted at Argonne National Labs is:

- http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/tutorial/mpiexmpl/src2/io/C/main.html

Comment: The first three URLs are no longer valid :(

Comment: @HristoIliev - Hmm.  This is a pretty terrible answer anyway (and not a great question).  Is there some good MPI master-worker Q&A we can point this question to and delete the answer?

Comment: I couldn't find such. Actually, I found this answer while looking for one.

Comment: @HristoIliev I deleted the broken links for now, but that's doesn't really address the other problems.